# R extension for visual studio does not identify terminal

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

I keep getting this:

[image]

I set the Rpath for the extension like so:

[image]

Is there anything else I can do to overcome the issue?

Comment: Since you're on Windows, don't you need to escape the backslashes? For example: `C:\\R\\R-4.1.2\\bin\\R.exe`. My Rpath looks like this: `"r.rpath.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.1.2\\bin\\R.exe"`

Comment: Hi, this looks like a rare error in vscode-R. Hopefully it has gone away now because of changes in vscode-R and/or VS Code itself, but if you still encounter this please follow the instructions in the error message to help the vscode-R developers debug the problem.

Comment: yes it has gone away. should I delete question?

Comment: @cs0815 Great to hear! I don't think you should delete the question.